# Validity of different explicit forms of an arbitrary element of SO(3)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

The usual generators of SO(3) are given in the "Lie Algebra" section of this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group. I will denote the generators $L_x, L_y, L_z$.

Using the exponential mapping, one would should be able to write an arbitrary element of SO(3) with $R(\theta, \varphi, \phi) = \exp(\theta L_x + \varphi L_z + \phi L_z)$ where $\theta, \varphi, \phi$ are parameters. Computing this exponential will give you an explicit form for an arbitrary element of SO(3).

However, wikipedia also writes under the "Mobius transformations" section that an arbitrary element of SO(3) may be written as $R(\theta, \varphi, \phi) = \exp(\theta L_x)\exp(\varphi L_y)\exp(\phi L_z)$.

We know that $[L_i, L_j] \neq 0$ for $i \neq j$. So the first explicit form is not equal to the second explicit form.

My question then is: are both of these explicit forms of an arbitrary element of SO(3) valid?

Comment: The answer is yes as you can convince yourself intuitively, but you're right that one does not follow trivially from the other. I don't know what the significance of both being true is. Is this a general property of (connected, compact) lie groups? I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I like this version, familiar from quaternions; all rational special orthogonal matrices occur  by taking $a,b,c,d$  integers, not all zero.
The more familiar appearance is   with the sum of the squares equal to one so the fraction disappears.

This is formula (10)  in [Pall 1940](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/%7Ekap/Pall_Automorphs_1940.pdf)

$$
\frac{1}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2} \;
\left( 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
 a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2 &   2(-ad+bc)  &  2(ac +bd  \\ 
 2(ad+bc) &  a^2 - b^2 + c^2 - d^2 &  2(-ab +cd)  \\ 
  2(-ac +bd)  & 2(ab +cd)  & a^2 - b^2 - c^2 + d^2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$$